# Trying to create a to-do list with js is not working?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am trying to create a mini to-do list project. Right now, I am trying to insert the value of the input element inside another the `<ul>` element using `insertAdjacentHTML()` and then I want to clear the input value when I click the button. However, nothing seems to be happening when I click the button.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Task Here" id="input">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add Task</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    const input = document.getElementbyId('input');
    const list = document.getElementbyId('list');
    let item = "<li> ${input.value} </li>";
    input.value = '';
    list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', item);
}
</script>

<ul id="list">
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The developer console will help you to debug these types of errors, hit f12 in most browsers to view the console

Comment: You are adding spaces before and after `input.value` - Is this a desired outcome or a result of mixed style of spacing and not spacing (I prefer the latter)?

Comment: I'd use `let item=document.createElement("li");
item.textContent=input.value;
input.value="";
list.append(item);` instead of `let item = \`<li> ${input.value} </li>\`;
input.value = '';
list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', item);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. It is `document.getElementById`, not `document.getElementbyId`.
2. Template literals are delimited by backticks (`` ` ``), not single or double quotes.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" placeholder="Enter Task Here" id="input">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Add Task</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    const input = document.getElementById('input');
    const list = document.getElementById('list');
    let item = `<li> ${input.value} </li>`;
    input.value = '';
    list.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', item);
}
</script>

<ul id="list">
</ul>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @chibiw3n Happy to help.